# The specified child already has a parent thrown when reopening a popup in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am creating a simple app that uses Google map in MAUI. I have added pins/markers to the map and now I want to show a popup when clicked on marker. I am using Community.Toolkit Popups. It works as expected for the first time, but when I close the popup and then click on the same marker again it throws Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.' I am testing it on Android.

This is my popup page.

```
   public class SightPopupPage : Popup {
       public SightPopupPage(ExtendedPin pin) {
       VerticalStackLayout layout = new VerticalStackLayout();
       layout.Add(new Label() { Text = pin.Label });
       layout.Add(pin.IntroImage);
       layout.Add(new Label() { Text = pin.Description });
       Content = layout;
   }
```

And this is the event handler:

```
private void markerClicked(object sender, PinClickedEventArgs e) {
    SightPopupPage popup = new SightPopupPage((ExtendedPin)sender);
    this.ShowPopup(popup);
}
```

The exception is thrown at the `this.ShowPopup(popup);` line. This is probably something trivial, but I am unable to find the answer elsewhere or figure it out myself as I have very little experience with MAUI or Android development. Thanks.

Comment: The marker need to be removed when the popup gets closed.  The marker no long contains a popup after you close the popup.  One solution is capture the close event and instead of closing the popup set visible = false to popup still exists.  The make visible when you click the marker.

Comment: What happens in `ShowPopup(popup);`? Where does it come from? Can you show that method?

Comment: @Julian https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup This is the documentation for this library. It talks about ShowPopup as well.

Comment: @jdweng Interesting solution, could you maybe elaborate on why does the marker needs to be removed? The pins are added to the map initially once when the map is being created. When I create SightPopupPage, I don't add new pins I just take some of their properties and give it to the Popup, not the marker itself.

Comment: When you close the Popup the object is destroyed.  So the marker is then pointing to a null object.

Comment: @jdweng Oh I see, I expected that when the markerClicked event is captured, it creates a new popup every time. How is this not true? Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Have you tried to display [pop-ups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups) while clicking on markers? Will this problem arise?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have after you told me to. It works, but I don't think it allows me to show a picture in this display. But in the documentation you sent me, it says down bellow that it is somehow possible to add entire page that would act like this display popup. If this is true, than it would be perfect thank you.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I have but I didn't need it at the end. It was probably another bug in MAUI. I didn't change anything in the marker's structure or in the handler itselft, yet it works now how intended. Since I am still unsure what caused it, I haven't posted selft-answering post.